# systemd with DynamicUser UID unknown

Tags: systemd

## problem

systemd has a DynamicUser feature, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#DynamicUser=

i'm also using: `PermissionsStartOnly=true` to change the permissions, since this requires root.

however, while the `ExecStart` knows the correct UID of that dynamic user, `ExecStartPost` and `ExecStartPre` won't know it as they are run as root (UID=0) and so i don't know how to chown it.

**wish: i'd like to use the dynamic user aspect of systemd but without knowing the UID i can't chown the documents so they can be accessed by the dynamic user.**

## question

is there something else in systemd which i can use to map the permissions of the files to this temporary user?

## code with a 'static' user:

```
acmeSupplied = fold (identifier: con: if (config.nixcloud.TLS.certs.${identifier}.mode) == "ACME" then con ++ [
  (nameValuePair "nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-${identifier}" (let
    c = config.nixcloud.TLS.certs.${identifier};
    allDomains = concatMapStringsSep " " (x: "--domains=${x}") ( [ c.domain ] ++ c.extraDomains);
    email = if (isString c.email) then c.email else "info@${c.domain}";
    hash = hashIdentifierACMEOptions identifier;
  in {
    description = "nixcloud.TLS: create acmeSupplied certificate for ${identifier}";
    preStart = ''
      mkdir -p ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied/${hash}
      chmod 0750 ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied -R
      chown nc-lego:${filterIdentifier identifier} ${stateDir}/${identifier} -R
    '';
    script = ''
      cd ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied
      ${pkgs.nixcloud.lego}/bin/lego ${allDomains} --email=${email} --exclude=dns-01 --exclude=tls-alpn-01 --webroot=/run/nixcloud/lego/${identifier}/challenges --path=${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied/${hash} --accept-tos --server=${c.acmeApiEndpoint} run
      ${pkgs.nixcloud.lego}/bin/lego ${allDomains} --email=${email} --exclude=dns-01 --exclude=tls-alpn-01 --webroot=/run/nixcloud/lego/${identifier}/challenges --path=${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied/${hash} --accept-tos --server=${c.acmeApiEndpoint} renew --days 15
    '';
   postStart = ''
      chown nc-lego:${filterIdentifier identifier} ${stateDir}/${identifier} -R
      chmod 0750 ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied -R
    '';
    serviceConfig = {
      #DynamicUser = true;
      User = "nc-lego";
      ReadWritePaths = "-${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied";
      SupplementaryGroups = "${filterIdentifier identifier}";
      PermissionsStartOnly = true;
      Type = "oneshot";
      RuntimeDirectory = "nixcloud/lego/${identifier}/challenges";
    };
    before = [ "nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-certificates.target" ];
    wantedBy = [ "nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-certificates.target" ];
  }))
] else con) [] (attrNames config.nixcloud.TLS.certs);
```

## code with a 'DynamicUser':

```
acmeSupplied = fold (identifier: con: if (config.nixcloud.TLS.certs.${identifier}.mode) == "ACME" then con ++ [
  (nameValuePair "nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-${identifier}" (let
    c = config.nixcloud.TLS.certs.${identifier};
    allDomains = concatMapStringsSep " " (x: "--domains=${x}") ( [ c.domain ] ++ c.extraDomains);
    email = if (isString c.email) then c.email else "info@${c.domain}";
    hash = hashIdentifierACMEOptions identifier;
  in {
    description = "nixcloud.TLS: create acmeSupplied certificate for ${identifier}";
    preStart = ''
      mkdir -p ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied/${hash}
      chmod 0750 ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied -R
      chown nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt:${filterIdentifier identifier} ${stateDir}/${identifier} -R
    '';
    script = ''
      cd ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied
      ${pkgs.nixcloud.lego}/bin/lego ${allDomains} --email=${email} --exclude=dns-01 --exclude=tls-alpn-01 --webroot=/run/nixcloud/lego/${identifier}/challenges --path=${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied/${hash} --accept-tos --server=${c.acmeApiEndpoint} run
      ${pkgs.nixcloud.lego}/bin/lego ${allDomains} --email=${email} --exclude=dns-01 --exclude=tls-alpn-01 --webroot=/run/nixcloud/lego/${identifier}/challenges --path=${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied/${hash} --accept-tos --server=${c.acmeApiEndpoint} renew --days 15
    '';
   postStart = ''
      chown nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt:${filterIdentifier identifier} ${stateDir}/${identifier} -R
      chmod 0750 ${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied -R
    '';
    serviceConfig = {
      DynamicUser = true;
      ReadWritePaths = "-${stateDir}/${identifier}/acmeSupplied";
      SupplementaryGroups = "${filterIdentifier identifier}";
      PermissionsStartOnly = true;
      Type = "oneshot";
      RuntimeDirectory = "nixcloud/lego/${identifier}/challenges";
    };
    before = [ "nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-certificates.target" ];
    wantedBy = [ "nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-certificates.target" ];
  }))
] else con) [] (attrNames config.nixcloud.TLS.certs);
```

the error message:

```
mailserver-nix-lt> updating GRUB 2 menu...
mailserver-nix-lt> activating the configuration...
mailserver-nix-lt> setting up /etc...
mailserver-nix-lt> setting up tmpfiles
mailserver-nix-lt> reloading the following units: dbus.service
mailserver-nix-lt> warning: the following units failed: nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt.service
mailserver-nix-lt> 
mailserver-nix-lt> ● nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt.service - nixcloud.TLS: create acmeSupplied certificate for mail.nix.lt
mailserver-nix-lt>    Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/i4nxkvw8bf9vs2brhj3lyjakxklq0rxg-unit-nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt.service/nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
mailserver-nix-lt>    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-10-11 10:55:46 CEST; 22ms ago
mailserver-nix-lt>   Process: 20613 ExecStartPre=/nix/store/c69ccjnc2n5y6g1p9q168kjlgf2w3l10-unit-script/bin/nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt-pre-start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
mailserver-nix-lt>  Main PID: 20243 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
mailserver-nix-lt> 
mailserver-nix-lt> Oct 11 10:55:46 mail.nix.lt systemd[1]: Starting nixcloud.TLS: create acmeSupplied certificate for mail.nix.lt...
mailserver-nix-lt> Oct 11 10:55:46 mail.nix.lt nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt-pre-start[20613]: chown: invalid user: ‘nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt:nc-mail-nix-lt’
mailserver-nix-lt> Oct 11 10:55:46 mail.nix.lt systemd[1]: nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
mailserver-nix-lt> Oct 11 10:55:46 mail.nix.lt systemd[1]: nixcloud.TLS-acmeSupplied-mail.nix.lt.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mailserver-nix-lt> Oct 11 10:55:46 mail.nix.lt systemd[1]: Failed to start nixcloud.TLS: create acmeSupplied certificate for mail.nix.lt.
mailserver-nix-lt> error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/ixarqxfbhr06fp8y8pj5dcm1rhar2j15-nixops-1.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nixops/deployment.py", line 731, in worker
    raise Exception("unable to activate new configuration")
Exception: unable to activate new configuration
```

as the documentation states on `DynamicUser`:

```
If these options are not used and
           dynamic user/group allocation is enabled for a unit, the name of
           the dynamic user/group is implicitly derived from the unit name.
           If the unit name without the type suffix qualifies as valid user
           name it is used directly, otherwise a name incorporating a hash
           of it is used.
```

but what is this hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> however, while the ExecStart knows the correct UID of that dynamic user, **ExecStartPost and ExecStartPre** won't know it as they **are run as root (UID=0)** and so i don't know how to chown it.

I don’t think that’s true – `ExecStartPre=` and `ExecStartPost=` run as the same `User=` and `Group=` (and with the same `CapabilityBoundingSet=`, `SystemCallFilter=`, etc. etc.) as the main executable, unless configured differently (using the `+`, `!` or `!!` prefix – see `man 5 systemd.service`). I tested it [with this test service](https://gist.github.com/lucaswerkmeister/850b6def64d7602566a2ddb753d80c25).

> wish: i'd like to use the dynamic user aspect of systemd but without knowing the UID **i can't chown the documents** so they can be accessed by the dynamic user.

This is not supposed to be necessary. Your service should store state in its `StateDirectory=`, runtime files in its `RuntimeDirectory=`, cache data in its `CacheDirectory=`, logs in its `LogsDirectory=` (if it has any logging of its own – but consider using the journal), and read config from its `ConfigurationDirectory=` (but that’s not writable to the service anyways). systemd will manage the ownership of those directories automatically for you, and they follow standard UNIX conventions (they’re subdirectories below `/var/lib`, `/run`, `/var/cache`, `/var/log`, `/etc` – see `man 5 systemd.exec` and [this blog post](http://0pointer.net/blog/dynamic-users-with-systemd.html) for details).

If your daemon can’t be limited to these standard directories, then the simplest solution is probably to not use `DynamicUser=` – there’s no shame in using a statically allocated user for more complicated setups. But consider creating the user via `systemd-sysusers` (see `man 5 sysusers.d`) instead of invoking `adduser`/`useradd` directly, especially if you’re writing a distribution package, so that it’s obvious which package installed the user (by checking which package owns the respective `systemd-sysusers` configuration file).

Comment: the service in question executes let's encrypt ACME client `lego` and the nginx (reverse-proxy) must be able to read the fiels. so we implemented it the way you recommend: a newly user called `nixcloud-lego-user`. thanks for your help!

Comment: To make files accessible between services, I sometimes set `UMask=0002` (so that files are group-writable by default) and then make both services be members of the same group. Perhaps you can try that as well?